# How to specify the paths for different models in rails in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

How to specify the paths for different models after signin in devise on rails? as i have two models namely customer and agent, how to specify different paths for different models

Comment: how about [devise_scope](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FMapper%3Adevise_scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can check within the login method whether the user is an agent or a customer.

The routes file generates a route for each view of rails. You can call them inside this if.

So you can do something like this:

```
def login
  ...
  if @user.customer?
    render :customer_dashboard
  else
    render :agent_dashboard
  end

end
```